# The type or namespace name 'Dts' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.SqlServer' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: ssis, script-task, biml

I am writing BIML file and added scripttask project. The code snippet is as below

```
<ScriptTaskProject Name="CollectRecordIds" ProjectCoreName="ST_39671a219bda455a9ac64f4384d10901" EntryPoint="Main">
        <AssemblyReferences>
            <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll"/>
            <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="Microsoft.SqlServer.ScriptTask.dll"/>
            <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="System.dll"/>
            <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="System.Data.dll"/>
            <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="System.Windows.Forms.dll"/>
            <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="System.Xml.dll"/>
        </AssemblyReferences>
       <ReadOnlyVariables>
            <Variable DataType="String" VariableName="rootFolder"/>
        </ReadOnlyVariables>
        <ReadWriteVariables>
            <Variable DataType="String" VariableName="recordids"/>
        </ReadWriteVariables>
        <Files>
            <File Path="ScriptMain.cs">
                using System;
                using System.Data;
                using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
                using System.Data.OleDb;
                using System.IO;
                namespace ST_39671a219bda455a9ac64f4384d10901
                {
                    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
                    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
                    {
                        public void Main()
                        {

                            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
                        }
                        enum ScriptResults
                        {
                            Success = DTSExecResult.Success,
                            Failure = DTSExecResult.Failure
                        };
                    }
                }
            </File>
        </Files>
    </ScriptTaskProject>
```

On BI Project Visual Studio 2015, I am successfully able to generate SSIS Package from this BIML code.

From SSIS packages when I try to open the the generated package I getting an error as below.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>
> Error     Error loading package.dtsx: CS0234 - The type or namespace name
>   'Dts' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.SqlServer' (are you
>   missing an assembly reference?), ScriptMain.cs, 9,
>   76        C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\Project\CollectIDs\package.dtsx 1

The issue gets resolved when I go **Script task Editor** and click **OK** and **save** package. I have some 1000 packages, I can't do this manual task even though it resolves my issue.

I have tried `AssemblyReferences` with relative and absolute path, but nothing worked. Why I am getting this error just after package generated from BIML?

Answer (score 0):

Check the Compiler Error... there is a good chance that with a later version you'll need to upgrade to a more recent version of MicrosoftSQLServerManagedDTS using NuGet.  My error for the DTS was removed when I did so but it added a new error about the namespace "Tasks"[image]